# Custom search in React bootstrap table: Uncaught TypeError: e.onSearch is not a function

Tags: reactjs, search, customization, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

i'm using react-bootstrap-table2 and want to custom search. I'm using ToolkitProvider
I get the following error:
react-dom.production.min.js:52 Uncaught TypeError: e.onSearch is not a function
Code:

```
const MySearch = (props) => {
  let input;
  const handleClick = () => {
    props.onSearch(input.value);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <label>
        OPTIONS:
        <select ref={(n) => (input = n)}>
          <option value="option1">OPTION1</option>
          <option value="option2">OPTION2</option>
          <option value="option3">OPTION3</option>
        </select>
      </label>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Search!!</button>
    </div>
  );
};
const MyTable = (props) => {
...

  return (
<ToolkitProvider
      keyField="id"
      data={data}
      columns={getColumns()}
      search
    >
      {(props) => (
        <>
          <MySearch {...props.searchProps} />
          <BootstrapTable
            {...props.baseProps}
          />
        </>
      )}
    </ToolkitProvider>)
    export default MyTable;
```

What to do?
Thanks

Comment: Code is not correct:I forgot the header of the function
````const MySearch = (props) => {
  let input; ....}
 ````

Comment: Just edit the question

Comment: Can you console.log(props)  in the MySearch component and see what are all the props?
FYI: It's a good practice to use PropTypes

Answer (score 0):

SUMIT NIHALANI
Result of console.log(props):

{}**proto**: constructor: ƒ Object()arguments: (...)assign: ƒ assign()caller: (...)create: ƒ create()defineProperties: ƒ defineProperties()defineProperty: ƒ defineProperty()entries: ƒ entries()freeze: ƒ freeze()fromEntries: ƒ fromEntries()getOwnPropertyDescriptor: ƒ getOwnPropertyDescriptor()getOwnPropertyDescriptors: ƒ getOwnPropertyDescriptors()getOwnPropertyNames: ƒ getOwnPropertyNames()getOwnPropertySymbols: ƒ getOwnPropertySymbols()getPrototypeOf: ƒ getPrototypeOf()is: ƒ is()isExtensible: ƒ isExtensible()isFrozen: ƒ isFrozen()isSealed: ƒ isSealed()keys: ƒ keys()length: 1name: "Object"preventExtensions: ƒ preventExtensions()prototype: {constructor: ƒ, **defineGetter**: ƒ, **defineSetter**: ƒ, hasOwnProperty: ƒ, **lookupGetter**: ƒ, …}seal: ƒ seal()setPrototypeOf: ƒ setPrototypeOf()values: ƒ values()**proto**: ƒ ()[[Scopes]]: Scopes[0]hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()arguments: (...)caller: (...)length: 1name: "hasOwnProperty"**proto**: ƒ ()[[Scopes]]: Scopes[0]isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()toString: ƒ toString()valueOf: ƒ valueOf()**defineGetter**: ƒ **defineGetter**()**defineSetter**: ƒ **defineSetter**()**lookupGetter**: ƒ **lookupGetter**()**lookupSetter**: ƒ **lookupSetter**()get **proto**: ƒ **proto**()set **proto**: ƒ **proto**()